# How can I randomize a data set groupwize in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have replications of the same clone.

How can I randomize my data set in such way that the each clone is randomized, but the replications stay together? So that the left column becomes for example the right one?

```
      Clone  V2  V3  V4               Clone  V2  V3  V4
1    1201K_1 GS1  1 167        4   12419S_13 GS1  1 279
2    1201K_1 GS1  1 355        5   12419S_13 GS1  1 287
3    1201K_1 GS1  1 515        9    12468S_6 GS1  1 167
4  12419S_13 GS1  1 279        10   12468S_6 GS1  1 260
5  12419S_13 GS1  1 287        6   12468S_18 GS1  1 320
6  12468S_18 GS1  1 320        7   12468S_18 GS1  1 338
7  12468S_18 GS1  1 338        8   12468S_18 GS1  1 594
8  12468S_18 GS1  1 594        1     1201K_1 GS1  1 167 
9   12468S_6 GS1  1 167        2     1201K_1 GS1  1 355 
10  12468S_6 GS1  1 260        3     1201K_1 GS1  1 515
```

Comment: use `dput` to provide reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create example data
dt <- read.csv(text = "Clone, V2, V3, V4
               1201K_1, GS1, 1, 167
               1201K_1, GS1, 1, 355
               1201K_1, GS1, 1, 515
               12419S_13, GS1, 1, 279
               12419S_13, GS1, 1, 287
               12468S_18, GS1, 1, 320
               12468S_18, GS1, 1, 338
               12468S_18, GS1, 1, 594 
               12468S_6, GS1, 1, 167
               12468S_6, GS1, 1, 260")

# Set Seed
set.seed(1200)

# Split the data frame based on Clone and store them in a list
dt_list <- split(dt, f = dt$Clone)

# Create a new index and change the order of dt_list
# Save the result to dt_list2
dt_list2 <- dt_list[sample(1:length(dt_list), length(dt_list))]

# Combine each data frame
dt2 <- do.call(rbind, dt_list2)

# See the result
dt2
                                      Clone   V2 V3  V4
       1201K_1.1                    1201K_1  GS1  1 167
       1201K_1.2                    1201K_1  GS1  1 355
       1201K_1.3                    1201K_1  GS1  1 515
       12419S_13.4                12419S_13  GS1  1 279
       12419S_13.5                12419S_13  GS1  1 287
       12468S_6.9                  12468S_6  GS1  1 167
       12468S_6.10                 12468S_6  GS1  1 260
       12468S_18.6                12468S_18  GS1  1 320
       12468S_18.7                12468S_18  GS1  1 338
       12468S_18.8                12468S_18  GS1  1 594
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is ordinary sampling. I am looking for how to do it groupwize.

Comment: @Uwe Thanks for your comment. I have updated my post to include `set.seed` and the ouput.

Answer (score 0):

Concluding from the provided sample data, the OP wants to change the order of `Clone` groups within the data set but not the order of rows within each `Clone` group.

This can be achieved by converting `Clone` to factor (if it is not already a factor) and to shuffle the factor levels using the `fct_shuffle()` function from the `forcats` package:

```
dt <- readr::read_csv(
"Clone, V2, V3, V4
1201K_1, GS1, 1, 167
1201K_1, GS1, 1, 355
1201K_1, GS1, 1, 515
12419S_13, GS1, 1, 279
12419S_13, GS1, 1, 287
12468S_18, GS1, 1, 320
12468S_18, GS1, 1, 338
12468S_18, GS1, 1, 594 
12468S_6, GS1, 1, 167
12468S_6, GS1, 1, 260")

# order Clone alphabetically
dt[order(dt$Clone), ]
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 4
>        Clone    V2    V3    V4
>       <fctr> <chr> <int> <int>
>  1 12468S_18   GS1     1   320
>  2 12468S_18   GS1     1   338
>  3 12468S_18   GS1     1   594
>  4   1201K_1   GS1     1   167
>  5   1201K_1   GS1     1   355
>  6   1201K_1   GS1     1   515
>  7  12468S_6   GS1     1   167
>  8  12468S_6   GS1     1   260
>  9 12419S_13   GS1     1   279
> 10 12419S_13   GS1     1   287
> ```

```
# randomly permute factor levels
dt$Clone <- forcats::fct_shuffle(dt$Clone)
dt[order(dt$Clone), ]
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 4
>        Clone    V2    V3    V4
>       <fctr> <chr> <int> <int>
>  1   1201K_1   GS1     1   167
>  2   1201K_1   GS1     1   355
>  3   1201K_1   GS1     1   515
>  4  12468S_6   GS1     1   167
>  5  12468S_6   GS1     1   260
>  6 12468S_18   GS1     1   320
>  7 12468S_18   GS1     1   338
>  8 12468S_18   GS1     1   594
>  9 12419S_13   GS1     1   279
> 10 12419S_13   GS1     1   287
> ```

```
# repeat: randomly permute factor levels
dt$Clone <- forcats::fct_shuffle(dt$Clone)
dt[order(dt$Clone), ]
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 4
>        Clone    V2    V3    V4
>       <fctr> <chr> <int> <int>
>  1 12468S_18   GS1     1   320
>  2 12468S_18   GS1     1   338
>  3 12468S_18   GS1     1   594
>  4  12468S_6   GS1     1   167
>  5  12468S_6   GS1     1   260
>  6   1201K_1   GS1     1   167
>  7   1201K_1   GS1     1   355
>  8   1201K_1   GS1     1   515
>  9 12419S_13   GS1     1   279
> 10 12419S_13   GS1     1   287
> ```